# What return type should Retrofit interface have? How do you handle exceptions?

Tags: android, json, retrofit, retrofit2, moshi

I'm trying to use Kotlin coroutines, with Retrofit and Moshi. But I'm confused based off the information that I'm seeing what I should be doing with my retrofit interface and how to handle the network exceptions.

In my interface, should I return:

1. `List<Data>`
2. `Response<List<Data>>`
3. `Call<List<Data>>`

What's the difference between all of these?

Then when I'm calling these interface methods, how do I catch network exceptions? Is it as simple as just wrapping it in a `try catch` block? Would a `try catch` block work for any of the above interface return types (eg. if interface returns `List<Data>` will that properly throw an exception)?